# Pig Script: STORE command not working

Tags: python, shell, hadoop, apache-pig

this is my first time posting to StackOverflow and I'm hoping someone can assist. I'm fairly new at pig scripts and have encountered a problem I can't solve.

Below is a pig script that fails when I attempt to write results to a file:

```
register 'myudf.py' using jython as myfuncs;
A = LOAD '$file_nm' USING PigStorage('$delimiter') AS ($fields);
B = FILTER A by ($field_nm) IS NOT NULL;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE ($field_nm) as fld;
D = GROUP C ALL;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE myfuncs.theResult(C.fld);
--DUMP E;
STORE E INTO 'myoutput/theResult';
EXEC;
```

I see the results of E when I Dump to the screen. However, I need to store the results temporarily in a file. After the Store command, the error I receive is: **Output Location Validation Failed**.

I've tried numerous workarounds, like removing the theResult folder and removing the earlier contents of theResult, but none of the commands I use work. These have been along the lines of:

```
hdfs dfs -rm myoutput/theResult
```

and

```
hadoop fs -rm myoutput/theResult
```

...using both the shell (hs) and file system (fs) commands. I've tried to call another function (shell script, python function, etc.) to clear the earlier results stored in the myoutput/theResult folder. I've read every website I can find and nothing is working. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

the output location of a mapreduce is a directory. So, you must have tried it this way

```
hadoop fs -rmr myoutput/theResult
```

and then run the pig script. It will work.
"rmr" - remove recursive, which deletes both folder/file
"rm" - is just remove which removes only file

Everytime, you need to either change output path or delete and use the same, since HDFS is **worm**(write once read many) model storage.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try-

1. making sure output director is a valid path.
2. Remove the entire directory and not just content within it. Remove directory with 'rmr and check that path doesn't exist before running pig script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for both of your replies. I now have a solution that is working:

```
fs -mkdir -p myoutput/theResult
fs -rm -r myoutput/theResult
```

The first line attempts to create a directory, but the "-p" prevents an error if it already exists. Then the second line removes it. Either way, there will be a directory to remove, so no error!

Answer (score 0):

The output of store is confusing when we are using Pig for the first time.

```
store grp into '/output1';
```

**This will create the folder named 'output1' in root. The folder should not be already present**

You can give your own hdfs path here like /user/thewhitetulip.

```
hdfs dfs -ls /output1
```

output:

```
/output1/_SUCCESS
/output1/part-r-00000
```

The part-r-00000 file is the output of the store program.